# Name for three-valued sign $+, -, 0$

Tags: soft-question, terminology, number-systems

Is there an accepted term (an adjective or prefix) like *strict*, *trichotomous*, *strong* or *definite* sign to indicate the three-valued sign whose values are $+$, $-$, and $0$?

Are there words reserved for this use in mathematical languages besides English?

An example is functions or differential equation solutions that do not change "sgn".  So to speak.

*Edit*.  The phrase should retain the word "sign" and add to it an adjective, prefix or (less likely) a suffix.  So, "super-sign (it)" is hypothetically a candidate, but not necessarily signito, sssignnnn, signulus, signifier, signiance, signplusplus.

Comment: English is not a mathematical language. There is mathematical notation. There are human natural languages, one of which is English. Mathematical notation is more likely to be understood by speakers of any language. For example, even though some notation uses Greek letters, that doesn't mean it is more or less understandable to those who do or don't understand the Greek language.

Comment: @FeralOink, there is mathematical English, and I was asking about mathematical X, where X runs over the non-English languages, but the difference between (mathematical (languages besides English)) and ((mathematical languages) besides English) is another thing that does not have a completely natural expression given the difficulty of simulating parentheses.  Maybe "mathematical vocabulary of languages other than English".

Comment: Much better! This: `mathematical vocabulary of languages other than English` is a fine way to express that which you seek. The SE site that indicates my expertise most clearly is English EL&U SE. So I do have some credibility ;o) maybe ;o)

Answer (score 3):

The [signum function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) meets your criteria.

Comment: It does not, which is the reason that I wrote this function into the question.  Also, I do not know how to pronounce it when speaking (sgn, that is).  Really I am looking for an understandable adjective to say before the word "sign".  Thanks for the answer, in any case.

Comment: For example, if I say "the solutions never change _____ sign" it is hoped that it would be comprehensible to people, including many mathematicians, who do not know the definition of sgn(x) or the Latin word *signum* or that sgn() has a different value for zero.  And if it is not universally understood, then placing the extra word would hopefully work as a clue that something more specific than "sign" is meant, which would either suggest the answer in context, or prompt questions if they are needed.

Comment: I have edited to make clear(er) that intent is a phrase that includes the word "sign", presumably following an adjective or prefix.

Comment: @zyx, it is hard to come up with an argument that "signum" doesn't contain the word "sign".

Comment: @TonyK, "um" is not a suffix in English.  Signum is a Latin word that has a related English word as its first four letters.  I think that mathematically literate individuals (including mathematicians) are far from universally aware of the definition of sgn(0) or the word "signum" designating that function definition, especially as a spoken word.  It is clearer in some European languages and in nations where the sgn notation is used more often in the education system.

Comment: Hmm. It seems to me that it is just as hard to come up with an argument that "sgn" _does_ contain the word "sign".

Comment: @TonyK, the clearly stated request preceding your comments was for "a phrase that includes the word *sign*", not a string of characters that includes the 4 letters s-i-g-n.   A phrase with sgn or signum as the replacement for "sign" does not contain the word 'sign'.  Signum is a reasonable answer for some other languages, such as Latin.

Comment: @zyx, You're probably right that "does not change signum" might not be clear to all mathematical audiences. It would be much better to use clear words as in "every solution is either strictly positive, constantly zero, or strictly negative". I don't think there is an adjective you can put in front of sign to represent this meaning clearly in English.

Comment: @MarkS., there were some Google hits for "strict sign" and "definite sign" used in the sense of the question. It would be great to be able to say 'time evolution preserves the strict sign of $U$' but I agree that there is probably no such common or best usage at the moment.  If there were a successful example in another living language, one could point to it as an argument to bring the equivalent into English.

Comment: @zyx Signum is close to answering your question, but does not meet all of your criteria, so I can understand the rationale for wanting something else. I don't believe that this is accurate though: "many mathematicians...do not know the definition of sgn(x) or the Latin word signum or that sgn() has a different value for zero...".

Comment: @FeralOink, I think step functions like sgn(x) and the Heaviside function are familiar, but the idea that the value of sgn($0$) is definitely required to be $0$, or that giving it any value at $0$ is meaningful in the contexts where it appears (e.g., as a distribution) is not universal.  And in some settings it should be continuous from the right or the left, for which $0$ is the wrong value.

Comment: Heaviside was the other function that crossed my mind too, regarding an answer to this question! I thought about it for about 30 minutes today, if I could answer with something meaningful, satisfying your criteria, but failed to find an answer. I like the question very much! I found a concept (and name) that is almost suitable, in computing. Computing is not mathematics, alas.

Comment: @FeralOink, on Wikipedia there is an entry for "three-valued comparison" in computer science which is quite close.